# Join Three tables - Spring data

Tags: hibernate, join, spring-data, hql

I have three tables namely: `student`, `student_info`, `student_hobbies`. `student_info` has two columns namely `stu_id` and `stu_hob`. `stu_id` is mapped to student id and `stu_hob` is mapped to `student_hobbies` `hob_id`.

We have corresponding java classes for student and student_hobbies. student_info doesnt have java class.

I wrote a join in spring data to retrieve the student hobby details.

```
@Query("select s from student s, student_info sinfo, student_hobbies lp  where s.id = sinfo.stu_id and sinfo.stu_hob = hob_id).
```

I am getting below error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: student_info is not mapped
```

That is because there is no java class called student_inf. Is it mandatory to create java class for student_info or is there any other way to get travelers hobbies.

```
 @Entity
    public class Student extends Profile {

        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private long id;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;    
    }

    @Entity
    public class StudentHobbies {

        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private long hob_id;
        private String bookname;
        private String bookdesc
    }


@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Profile extends AbstractStudent {

    @JoinTable(name = "student_info", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "stu_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "stu_hob", referencedColumnName = "hob_id"))
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
    private List<StudentHobbies> studentHobbies;

}
```

Comment: add entities please

Comment: Thanks for replying. Do u mean in java class, how are entities are mapped.

Comment: yes knowing how your classes maps the database is a great help to understand your situation and answer

Comment: I have added the entities.

Answer (score 0):

> That is because there is no java class called student_inf. Is it mandatory to create java class for student_info or is there any other way to get travelers hobbies.

Hql/Jpql only works if you have the Java classes mapping the existent tables on the database. In your case, you could have a `StudentInfo` class mapping the table `student_info` Without them, you can't write a HQL query.

If you can't create this class for any reason, the only way is abandon the HQL and use a native SQL.